# Multiple occurrence of "Oracle WebLogic Server 14.1.1.0 Demo Trust keystore" were found

Tags: eclipse, weblogic14c

Window > Preferences > WebLogic > Credentials

Multiple occurrence of "Oracle WebLogic Server 14.1.1.0 Demo Trust keystore" were found.
[image]

The error message should not come.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue in Eclipse, I deleted one of those entries as those were similar.

[image]